# resultant of a binomial and a trinomial

Tags: polynomials, resultant

Does anyone know of any papers dealing with the resultant of a binomial $x^n+a$ and a trinomial $x^r+bx^s+c$?

Even special cases would be of interest.

The resultant of two binomials is well known, see Lemma 3 in the 1962 paper ["Factorization of Polynomials over Finite Fields" by Richard Swan.](https://msp.org/pjm/1962/12-3/pjm-v12-n3-p27-p.pdf)

Comment: Hi Gary! I took the liberty of making that link clickable to (see the changes in the mark-iup code click the "edit" button below the post). Probably works better that way for future readers of this question.

Comment: [Crossposted at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/293034/15503).